# why webview not perform any action onclick of video in it?

Tags: android, uiwebview, video-streaming, android-webview

I have read RSS and get html string like at http://pastebin.com/eWQ6gUe2 which i display in webview so all images and decription will show but for video link either it show only black part or first frame of video with showing play button on it and onclick of that nothing happen so how to play video from that and why for some video link it show black part.
i have used this code for

```
        webview mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);         
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);          
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(false);
        mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
        mWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON_DEMAND);
        mWebView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
        mWebView.loadData(detail_des, "text/css","utf-8");

      where detail_des contain html string
```

Thanx in advance.
Hope for your regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're Android version is >= 3.0, have you declare

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```